# Dictionary comprehension within a list comprehension, per dictionary in other list

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I am attempting to create a list of dictionaries, where the dictionaries inside of the list are created from a preexisting list of dictionaries, for which a new dictionary should be created from the aggregate of the key-value pairs of each dictionary in the preexisting list of dictionaries, if the key is a member of another preexisting list (child_container).

Or in other words, I am trying to filter out the keys in the dictionaries (d) in a list of dictionaries (child_container) that are not members of list_multiple_tagnames.

```
[d for d in child_container if isinstance(d, dict) for k, v in d.iteritems() if k in lst_multiple_tagnames]
```

The intended effect is for a dictionary to be made PER dictionary d in child_container, with only the Key-Value pairs that are in lst_multiple_tagnames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dict comprehension must be used, the compounded for does not capture the per-key-per-dictionary scope.

```
[{k:v for k,v in d.iteritems() if k in lst_multiple_tagnames} for d in child_container if isinstance(d, dict)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
assume child_container = [{ 1:1,3:324,2:2334}, {1:123},{2:2}]
for d in child_container:
...     if isinstance(d,dict):
...         for k in d:
...             res[k] = res.get(k,[]) + [d[k]]
print res
{1: [1, 123], 2: [2334, 2], 3: [324]}
```